# How do I make a python script wait for sometime?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and I have written a single python script which does the following:

1. It does some operation and writes the details to a text file(say a.txt)
2. Once the txt file(a.file) is written, the same file is read to do some operations.

The problem I face is once the file(a.txt) is written and same is read, the contents are not read.

I use `time.sleep()` after the txt file(a.txt) is written and then proceeded with reading the same.

But whats happening is the script is stopping it's execution for the time period mentioned in the sleep method and the txt file is not read.

I need a scenario where the same script must write to a text file and read instantly.

Could someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Also, are you flushing the buffer after writing to it?

Comment: "I need a scenario where the same script must write to a text file and read the same instantly." Why?  This doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @DorShemer: Buffers are automatically flushed when closing the file. Supposedly that fact that this was forgotten caused the error.

Comment: if you have the file still open after writing, the position is at the end of the string - try http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek

Comment: I have seen a lot of new python programmers go directly to this method first, of writing their data to a file in one area of code, and then reading it in for use in another area. I don't think the concept of variables and passing them around has really clicked yet.

Answer (score 3):

If you write to a file, the "current position" is at the end of the file after the write. To read from the same file, you have to use the [seek](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) method to go to the start of the file.

```
foo = open("bla.txt", "w+")
foo.write("your text here")
foo.seek(0)
lines = foo.readlines()
```

Comment: Make sure you open the file with 'w+' (for updating), otherwise simply doing 'w' will not let you read from the file.

Comment: Upvoted because its the only answer so far that doesn't open the file twice.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the file you just wrote it should only be necessary to close the file (thus flushing the buffer), you shouldn't need to block with the sleep method, for example

```
filepath="myfilepath"
with open(filepath,'w') as f:
    f.write("hello")

with open(filepath,'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

In this case the "with" keyword automatically calls f.close() on the file when it's block is closed. The "with" keyword does not work in early versions of python. The above is equivalent to doing this explicitly:

```
filepath="myfilepath"
f = open(filepath,'w')
f.write("hello")
f.close()
f = open(filepath,'r')
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

The close function flushes the buffer.

Depending of your use case it might be better to use some other type of data structure to store your temporary value like a simple variable. Have fun learning python.

Edit: the "with" statement was introduced in python 2.5

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the approach is not the best in this case.

Why would you ever need to sequentially write and read on exactly the same file?

It looks like you're doing something like

```
while True:
     big_string = generate_big_string()
     open(filename, 'w').write(big_string)
     big_string = open(filename).read()
```

if that's the case then just keep the string in memory, there is no point in writing and reading all the time.
If it's not the case then you should probably post some code to get better help.